# how to import CSV using zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, csv

How do I import CSV files using zend framework? Should I use zend_file_transfer or is there any special class that I have to look into? Also if I use zend_file_transfer is there any special validator for CSV?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no class to parse CSV in Zend (unless you're looking to parse a translation file with Zend_Translate or if you're using Zend_Auth with CSV files). It's pretty straightforward with `fgetcsv` so I guess there's no need for a class there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you don't have to use any zend libraries to import csv files, you can just use native php functions, take a look at [fgetcsv](http://us.php.net/fgetcsv)

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Side warning: `fgetcsv()` doesn't really support unicode, so you might need to juggle locales.

Comment: yeah, I know how to do it using fgetcsv but I am specifically interested via zend. Thanks for your reply anyways.

Comment: Built in CSV functions are flawed and buggy. It is a nightmare to try to parse CSV in native PHP.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use `SplFileObject` for reading CSV files.

From the php manual:

```
<?php
    $file = new SplFileObject("animals.csv");
    $file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    foreach ($file as $row) {
        list($animal, $class, $legs) = $row;
        printf("A %s is a %s with %d legs\n", $animal, $class, $legs);
    }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php

Comment: SplFileObject doesn't provide any useful validation/errors -- passing in rubbish will just result in $row being an array of one element where the element is the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this with the Zend Framework. How can one be sure?

For example, **Zend_Translate** supports translation with CSV files, but if you check the the source code of the respective adapter (**Zend_Translate_Adapter_Csv**), you can verify it uses **fgetcsv**, and not a specific Zend class. Besides, this CSV adapter comes with the following warning:

> Note: Beware that the Csv Adapter has
>   problems when your Csv files are
>   encoded differently than the locale
>   setting of your environment. This is
>   due to a Bug of PHP itself which will
>   not be fixed before PHP 6.0
>   (http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38471).
>   So you should be aware that the Csv
>   Adapter due to PHP restrictions is not
>   locale aware.

which is related with the problems of the **fgetcsv** function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that reads a csv file and returns an array of items that contain the first two column data values.

This function could read a file of first_name,last_name for example.

```
function processFile ($filename) {
    $rtn = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $item = array();
            $item[] = $data[0];
            $item[] = $data[1];
            $rtn[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $rtn;
 }
```