# Can Zend Translate convert array to csv file?

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, csv

Can I use Zend_Translate to convert a data array into a csv file?

Comment: Why would you use Zend_Translate? A little more backstory would go a long way to more specific answers...

Comment: maybe zend translate is not the best tool?  on my searches it looks like it can handle CSV's

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. Post some code snippets and we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with plain php.

Implode the array and echo it out in csv format.

Comment: yeah but you need to escape comma's and quotes etc.  I thought there would be a package on the framework that would help with this

Comment: @user1030168 nothing to escape, just use explode and implode.

Comment: what if you have the following 


$data = array(); 
$data[] = 'this text'; 
$data[] = text , more 
$data[] = text , mo more,and more 

you would need

When you implode this array you would need to escape the comma's inside each data item

Answer (score 0):

found this... [how to import CSV using zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334354/how-to-import-csv-using-zend)

looks like zend translate is not the best option for what I was trying to do